# Surface integral calculation

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> Let $S$ be the surface defined by $y = 10 − x^2 − z^2$ with $y ≥ 1$,
>   oriented with rightward-pointing normal. Let
>
> $$\vec F = (2xyz + 5z) \vec i + e^x\cos(yz)\vec j + x^2y\vec k$$
>
> Determine
>
> $$\iint_S \nabla \times \vec F \cdot d\vec S$$

Usually I will try to find an answer and, once found, verify if it is correct using tools like MATLAB/Wolfram Alpha and occasionally Maple. I don't know however how to check my solution using computer programs when evaluating surface integrals over scalar or vector fields. Is there any way to do this?

For this particular problem I obtained an answer, but it is so easy to make a single mistake down the road that it is really hard to verify it myself. I would really appreciate if someone could check my reasoning and correct me when necessary.

First note that the surface is bounded by a closed parametric curve, $C = (3\sin \theta) \vec i + j + (3\cos \theta)\vec k$ and lies completely in the xz-plane dimension. By Stokes' theorem we can write

$$\iint_S \nabla \times \vec F \cdot d\vec S = \int_C \vec F \cdot d\vec r = \iint_A (\frac{\partial P}{\partial z}-\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x})dx\,dz = 5 \iint_A \, dx\,dz = 45\pi$$

The last equality follows from Greens theorem and the fact that $\frac{\partial P}{\partial z} = 2xy+5$ and $\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x} = 2xy$. $A$ represents the area of the circle $r=3$ at $(0, 1, 0)$.

PS. How do you typeset bold vector notation in $\LaTeX$? I don't really like the arrow ($\vec v$) notation outside of physics.

Comment: For bold vector notation, I do {\bf v} to get ${\bf v}$

Comment: @Tom Thanks Tom, just what I was looking for. I'm not sure what the convention is for bold/arrow notation. It always seemed to me like bold notation was preferred in general, but arrow notation was also allowed in physics.

Comment: You might check your partial of $P$ with respect to $z$. :) (Incidentally, the LaTeX command `$\mathbf{v}$` gives $\mathbf{v}$.)

Comment: @user86418 You see what I mean :)? So easy to overlook such small things even though you might completely comprehend the material. I edited my question, would you mind looking at it again? I thank you in advance for your trouble and time.

Comment: @Jori: I haven't carefully checked the details, but your answer looks right. :) Incidentally, many instructors would probably be fine with your jumping straight from $\iint_{S}$ to $\iint_{A}$ (perhaps with a line of explanation). Since the disk $A$ has "rightward" unit normal field $(0, 1, 0)$, only the second component of the curl contributes, and since the flux density of the curl is constant ($5$), the net flux is $5$ times the area of $A$.

Comment: @user86418 Thanks for your reply. Now looking at it again I think there is a second mistake namely the $\frac{\partial P}{\partial z}$ and $\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}$ should have been reversed, resulting in $-45\pi$.

Comment: @Jori: The second component of the curl is correct as you had it. The flux could be negative due to orientation of the surface (again, I haven't checked carefully), but the sign of the integrand is okay. :)